# Force gcc to put all code between prologue and epilogue

Tags: assembly, gcc, clang, compiler-optimization, compiler-flags

When I create very simple C function, something along these lines

```
void foo(int a) {
  for (int i=0; i < a; i++) {
    if (i < 4) {
      do_something()
    } else {
      do_something_else()
    }
  }
}
```

Gcc translates this to something like this (please excuse the very crude pseudocode).

```
# #Prologue
xor    eax,eax
:myloop
cmp    rax,0x3
ja     <:somethingelse>
# do_something()
add    rax,0x1
#test end of loop
ja     <:myloop>
# EPILOGUE
ret    
nop
:somethingelse
# do_something_else()
jmp    ce <logdata+0xbe>
```

I'd like to tell gcc to put all the code inside the prologue/epilogue block and not to put any code after the last `ret` instruction. `-O0` Kinda does it, but the generated code is big and slow. Is there any way how to achieve that? Other compilers and their options are welcome as well.

Comment: There is no such option. Also, a function might have multiple `ret` instructions or none at all.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you care: what are you trying to accomplish that would make this useful to you?  (Also, assembly language is available if you want to spell out the exact machine code and instruction sequencing.)

Comment: I'm injecting the generated code into other functions and need the block to be flexible, have 0 side effects and be easily changeable. I'll have to now put a jmp instruction before the final return and calculate the offset, which is pain a bit.